# Positioning a background image in a div to start at a certain point

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

I am trying to add a background image to a div that will extend the height of a page. My issue is that at the top of this div is a logo with a transparent background. I dont want the background image of the div to appear below the logo image.

Is there a way to tell the background image to not start appearing until a certain pixel point? So if the logo is 200px in height can i have the bg image not start appearing until 210px down within the div?

Comment: ok. i am not sure how to accept via the site?

Comment: Click on the check mark on the left of an answer and it will turn green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `background-clip: content-box;` - [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3144906)

Even better, you could set `background-clip: padding-box` and set a big transparent top border instead of a big transparent top padding to make sure it works in Opera as well - [**demo**](http://dabblet.com/gist/3144965).

Comment: thanks everyone. i ended up getting it to work by recutting the bg image to have the space atop it required to allow the logo to be transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `top:210px` to the css for that div.